# Undefined variable in array in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, undefined

I have the following code:

```
<ul id="litemsd">
 <li class="litemd">
  <input type="checkbox" id="d1" name="d1" />
  <label for="d1">Number One</label>
 </li>
 <li class="litemd">
  <input type="checkbox" id="d2" name="d2" />
  <label for="d2">Numer Two</label>
 </li>
 <li class="litemd">
  <input type="checkbox" id="d3" name="d3" />
  <label for="d3">Numer Three</label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And inside the form's submit observe function I try to iterate over the selected checkboxes:

```
$$('li.litemd').pluck('checked').each(function(s) {
  alert(s.next().innerHTML)
});
```

But whe that code is reached, the following error pops up in firebug:

```
"s is undefined"
```

Any hints ?

Comment: you should post what pluck does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing the properties which pluck() works on with HTML attributes. It's anyway easier to add the pseudo class of checked as part of the initial selector, like:

```
$$('li.litemd input:checked').each(function(s) {
      alert(s.next().innerHTML);
  });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tXXwD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$$('li.litemd').pluck('checked').each(function() {
  alert($$(this).next().innerHTML)
});
```

?

Comment: Nope, "$$(this).next is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

[`.pluck()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/pluck) returns an array of values (whatever property name you passed in), so it's not filtering your results to the `checked` ones, it's literally returning a `[false, false, false]` array.

Instead I think you want this:

```
$$('li.litemd input').each(function(s) {
  if(s.checked) alert(s.next().innerHTML)
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cPxnd/), note the addition of `input` to the selector, since you're cheking on the property of the `<input>` *inside* the `<li>`, not on the `<li>` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No errors but doesn't recognize the checked items.

Comment: @xain - It should, as in the demo...what behavior are you getting?